# Simple javascript: arrays, and form information gathering

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know javascript much at all, I just like making lists for myself. I am currently trying to create a html page that I can keep track of characters from my favorite game, but I have run across a couple of problems I don't know how to solve.

```
function overview ()
{
    var ov01=document.form.ov01.value;//file
    var ov02=document.form.ov02.value;//text
    var ov03=document.form.ov03.value;//text
    var ov04=document.form.ov04.value;//text
    var ov05=document.form.ov05.value;//radio
    var ov06=document.form.ov06.value;//select
    var ov07=document.form.ov07.value;//number
    var ov08=document.form.ov08.value;//text

document.result.endresult.value="<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Save Challenge Valley</title><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='./forSCV/scripts/SaveChallengeValley.css'><script type='text/javascript' src='./forSCV/scripts/onmouseover-out.js'></script></head><body><div id='container'><div id='title'><table id='title'><tr><td rowspan='2'><img src='//C:/Users/Nancy/Pictures/The Sims/Sims 2-familytrees/ChallengePhotos/alloyE.jpg' alt='Alloy Challenge' id='title' title='Alloy Challenge'></td><td><h1>Save Challenge Valley</h1></td><td rowspan='2'><img src='//C:/Users/Nancy/Pictures/The Sims/Sims 2-familytrees/ChallengePhotos/addisonE.jpg' alt='Addison Challenge' id='title' title='Addison Challenge'></td></tr><tr><td class='bottom'><b>"+ov02+""+ov04+"</b></td></tr></table></div><script type='text/javascript' src='./forSCV/scripts/menusSCV.js'></script><div id='easy1'><h2>Overview</h2><img src='//C:/Users/Nancy/Pictures/The Sims/Sims 2-familytrees/ChallengePhotos/'"+ov01+"' alt='"+ov02+" "+ov03+"' title='"+ov02+" "+ov03+"' class='overview1'><table class='overview2'><tr><td>Name:</td><td class='white'>"+ov02+""+ov04+" "+ov03+"</td></tr><tr><td>Treat as:</td><td class='white'>"+ov05+"</td></tr><tr><td>Life Section:</td><td class='white'>"+ov06+"</td></tr><tr><td>Remaining Days:</td><td class='white'>"+ov07+"</td></tr><tr><td>Catalog Desc.:</td><td class='white'>"+ov08+"</td></tr></table></div>"
}
```

When it comes time to click the button, I would like the value of ov04 (if available) to add a *space* and a *(*, then after it a *)*. I don't know how to make that happen. (Searching hasn't helped.)

Example: Amy (McCoy) Carter. ov02 is first name, ov03 is last name, and ov04 is maiden name.

I thought something like this might do it, but nope...

```
var space="";

    do {space +=" ("+ov04+")";
        ov04--;}
    while (ov04>=2);
```

Comment: Please focus on one problem per question. You can edit your post to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Names

```
var fullName = ov02 + " " + (ov04 ? "(" + ov04 + ") " : "") + ov03;
```

Array of selected option values from a `<select multiple>`

```
var opts = [].reduce.call(
  document.form.nl01.options, 
  function (c, el) { 
    if (el.selected) 
      c.push(el.value); 
    return c; 
  }, []);
```

Third.  You really shouldn't do that.  Make some container divs, and write to each one separately.

Answer (score 2):

Lets deal with adding some brackets around the maiden-name. One problem you're certainly having is the way you're treating ov04. It holds a string - the maiden name, yet you try to treat it as though it were a number, (`ov04--`) That just wont do!

I'll demonstrate with a function:

```
function makePrettyName(fistName, lastName, maidenName)
{
 var result;
 if (maidenName != "")
 {
    result = firstName + " (" + maidenName + ") " + lastName;
 }
 else
 {
    result = firstName + " " + lastName;
 }
 return result;
}
```

And an example of its use:

```
var tgtElem = document.getElementById(idOfTargetElementGoesHere);
tgtElem.innerText = makePrettyName(document.form.ov02.value, document.form.ov03.value, document.form.ov04.value);
```

I'll also point out that both your future self and anyone else you share code with will thank you if you get into the habit of using meaningful variable names. It takes *far* less time/effort to type the name out than it takes to continually mentally connect some arbitrary variable name to the data that it holds.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but how do I get it to first check that maidenName has a value (it is optional) and then to run the function and finally to add it to the document.result.endresult.value? if maidenName is present do firstName+(maidenName)+lastName else firstName+lastName?

Comment: @Nancy76 - I've altered the function. You basically had the if condition spot-on, but just didn't know how to check the value. I'm simply checking that the input element has a value (i.e, that it's not an empty string - which is what the input element gives you if its empty). If it doesn't hold a value, just proceed without the brackets or maiden-name. :)